# Edit multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to scale two layers up by the same amount, using **Edit** > **Transform** > **Scale**. 
Can I link the layers so that scaling one of the layers also affects the other by *exactly* the same amount?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click, to select multiple layers in the layers panel. Note (I believe it's <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on Mac).

Then click *Layer > Link Layers*.